# Getting the value from another table with the session username using SELECT (ASP.NET Core MVC)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, session

I'm very much new to ASP.NET Core MVC. I have two tables in my database, `[UserReg1]` for registering and `[UserInfo]` for getting the data, when the user register in the table `[UserReg1]`, I want to get all his information that is stored in table 2 `[UserInfo]`.

When a user registers, it is added to the database and passed the session to another controller and then I could get all the info in `[UserReg1]`.

What I need is to get the data of `[UserInfo]` when `UserName` is the same in `[UserReg1]`. I could not do that using the session any help?

Please let me know if you think there is a  better way to that (please not identity)

`UserReg1` and `UserInfo` classes

```
[Table("UserReg1")]
public class UserReg1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Dept Department { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `AccountController`'s `Register` action method:

```
public IActionResult Register(UserReg1 us)
{
    _appDbContex.Add(us);
    _appDbContex.SaveChanges();

    HttpContext.Session.SetString("SessionUserReg1", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(us));
    return RedirectToAction("ViewUser", "Home");
}
```

This is my `HomeContoller`'s `ViewUser` action method. Here I get the information for `[UserReg1]` but could not get the `FirstName` from `[UserInfo]`:

```
public IActionResult ViewUser()
{
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserReg1>(HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionUserReg1"));

    string Query = "SELECT [FirstName] FROM [UserInfo] WHERE [UserName] = '" + result.UserName + "'";

    string connectionString2 = _config["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];

    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString2);
    SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(Query, sqlConnection);
    sqlConnection.Open();

    sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConnection.Close();

    return View(result);
}
```

ViewUser View

```
@model EmployeeM.Models.UserReg1

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ViewUser";
}

<h1>ViewUser</h1>

<div>
    <h4>UserReg1</h4>
    <hr />
    <h4> User Id : @Model.id</h4>
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.id)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Password)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>
 <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserInfo.FirstName)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10"> 
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserInfo.FirstName)
        </dd>
@*FirstName doesn't retrieve any value*@

    </dl>
</div>
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id = Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` does not return a result set. You need to use `ExecuteReader` or `ExecuteScalar` or fill a `DataTable`. Unrelated, but your code is vulnerable to SQL injection (use parameters!) and you should `Dispose()` your connection and command resources in a `finally` or `using` block

Comment: @Crowcoder: or use Entity Framework that you seem to be using in your other code snippets - why fall back to "raw" SQL here??

Comment: @marc_s I don't consider EF to be the one thing everyone must use. If this project is already using ADO.NET then I'm not going to recommend re-architecting all data access because there is a problem with one query.

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm still in the beginning of building my app. so i can recreate the app from scratch.. do you recommend me to use another language for this demand? -

Comment: @FadiAkkad [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) is well worth learning if you want to build with something more modern.

Comment: @Crowcoder: well , in the `Register` method of the `AccountController`, it appears as if he's *already* using EF - so why mix? Why not use EF everywhere? Why fall back to low-level "raw" SQL and ADO.NET if EF is being used elsewhere in the project? That was my point

Comment: @marc_s agreed. Honestly I didn't even notice and I understand your comment now that I have more context.

Comment: Agree with @marc_s, if the project is based on .NET Core and already using and ORM like EF then you might also want to read about DI (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) to inject the dbContext in the HomeController. 
Once you manage to do that, getting the FirstName from the other table would be as simple as: 
`string firstName = _context.UserInfo.Where(x => x.UserName == result.Name).FirstOrDefault().FirstName;`